# Measurable representations of semi simple Lie groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a semi simple Lie group.  I'm particularly interested in $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$.  It is proved in

I. E. Segal and J. von Neumann, A theorem on unitary representations of semisimple
Lie groups, Annals of Mathematics 52 (1950), 509–517.

that measurable unitary representations of $G$ are actually continuous.  Is this also true for finite-dimensional non-unitary representations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is true and due to Béla von Szőkefalvi-Nagy, [*Über meßbare Darstellungen Liescher Gruppen* (1936)](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/resolveppn/?PPN=GDZPPN002278286). Generalized to finite-dimensional representations of locally compact groups in A. Weil, *L'intégration dans les groupes topologiques* (1940, p. 66). Also exposed in Hewitt-Ross, *Abstract harmonic analysis* (1963, p. 346) or Fell-Doran, [*Representations of $*$-algebras, etc.* (1988, p. 236)](https://books.google.com/books?id=tf_JCe5YPq8C&pg=PA236).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see the Encyclopaedia of Math article: http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Finite-dimensional_representation

Comment: This asserts the fact, but does not seem to give a reference (perhaps it is implied that this is in [7], but I can't even find this in MathSciNet [maybe because of a Russian-English transliteration issue]).  Can you give me a reference, preferably in English, French, or German?

Comment: Well, you asked if it was true, I gave you an answer with a credible reference. It would be correct to upvote.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to up vote.  Sorry.

Comment: The link no longer works