# Representation theory of SU(2) as a discrete group

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

The representation theory of the Lie group $SU(2)$ is well understood, easy to describe, and in fact central to the classical theory of representation theory of compact Lie groups.

But what happens if we ignore the smooth structure and even the topology on $SU(2)$ and simply see it as a discrete group? (I will write $SU(2)^{\delta}$ for this group in the following.) Three related questions one might ask are the following.

(1) Is there a 2-dimensional representation $SU(2)^{\delta} \to SL_2(\mathbb C)$ that is not conjugate to the inclusion $SU(2)^{\delta} \to SU(2) \subset SL_2(\mathbb C)$?

(2) Are there conditions on a representation that guarantee that it will be continuous/smooth?

(3) Is it possible to describe the complex irreducible representations of $SU(2)^{\delta}$?

Comment: What do you call "conjugate"? if you mean conjugate by an inner automorphism, there are more reps. If you mean by an automorphism of $SL_2(SL_2(\mathbf{C}))$, probably there's none. Additional reps are indeed by "conjugating" the standard rep by an automorphism of the field $\mathbf{C}$ (extended to $SL_2(\mathbf{C})$). For homomorphisms between Lie groups, continuous and smooth are the same; continuous reps of $SU(2)$ into $SL_2(\mathbf{C}$ are indeed all conjugate to the inclusion by an inner automorphism of the target group.

Comment: Finally (3) is probably tackled in Borel-Tits "homomorphismes abstraits de groupes algébriques simples", see https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970833?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents, or http://www.numdam.org/item/SB_1972-1973__15__307_0 for Steinberg's Bourbaki seminar account (the latter is in English).

Comment: Hmm, okay, that is kind of cheap. I did mean conjugate by an inner automorphism. And what about non-trivial endomorphisms of $SU(2)^{\delta}$. Are there any?

Comment: you should check in the given references, as it should answer your latter question.

Comment: For (2): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191682/measurable-representations-of-semi-simple-lie-groups. For (3), allowing infinite-dimensional irreps (you don't say): http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=248288.

Comment: @Jens: Probably you trying to ask too many questions here, but for example in (3) the cited paper by Borel-Tits in the algebraic group setting is best compared with a more focused follow-up article by TIts for real Lie groups (if you can track it down): http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0379749     But you do need to specify finite dimensional representations if that is assumed.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler What is the relevance of Thoma's paper here? AFAIK it deals with discrete Type I groups and shows they are virtually abelian

Comment: For the OP: I have not had time to look closely at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.05801 but does Theorem D answer your questions?

Comment: @YemonChoi Yes; so it implies that $\mathrm{SU}(2)^\delta$ is not Type I, hence in a sense a “no” answer to question (3) for unitary representations.